# comparing of two 2d-string arrays with different sizes

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I have the following 2-dimensional Arrays:

```
String[][] array1 = {{"hello", "hi"}{"bye", "two"}};
String[][] array2 = {{"hello", "hi", "three"}{"bye", "maybe", "third"}, {"3", "rd", "Element"}};
String[][] array3 = {{"hello", "hi"}{"bye", "two"}};
```

How can I check, whether they have the same values or not (different sizes)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`Arrays.deepEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

> `public static boolean deepEquals(Object[] a1,
>                    Object[] a2)`
>
> Returns true if the two specified arrays are deeply equal to one another. Unlike the `equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.
>
> Two array references are considered deeply equal if both are null, or if they refer to arrays that contain the same number of elements and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are deeply equal.
>
> Two possibly null elements `e1` and `e2` are deeply equal if any of the following conditions hold:
>
> - e1 and e2 are both arrays of object reference types, and Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2) would return true
> - e1 and e2 are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate overloading of Arrays.equals(e1, e2) would return true.
> - e1 == e2
> - e1.equals(e2) would return true.
>
> Note that this definition permits null elements at any depth.
>
> If either of the specified arrays contain themselves as elements either directly or indirectly through one or more levels of arrays, the behavior of this method is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create your own method:

```
public boolean compare(String[][] a, String[][] b){
    boolean result = true;
    int outer = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    int inner = Math.max(a[0].length, b[0].length);

    for(int i = 0; i<outer; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<inner; j++){
            if(i < a.length && i < b.length && j < a[0].length && j < b[0].length){
                if(!a[i][j].equals(b[i][j])){
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Certainly can - all depends on whether you're trying to solve this problem for a real-world problem, or trying to solve this problem as an intellectual exercise. :-)